# Physics.OverflowCapsule only working once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a sort of ground-pound functionality, to be activated when E is pressed, which pushes all nearby objects away from the player. This is what I have so far, which runs on FixedUpdate():

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && staminaBar.staminaBar.value == staminaBar.staminaBar.maxValue) {

            anim.SetTrigger("GroundPound");

            staminaBar.ChangeStamina(-50f);

            Collider[] targets = Physics.OverlapCapsule(topPoint, bottomPoint, 10f, playerMask);

            Debug.Log (targets.Length + " targets found.");

            foreach(Collider target in targets) {

                Debug.Log ("Targeted " + target.name);

                if (target.attachedRigidbody != null) {

                    target.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.Scale(target.transform.position - this.transform.position, new Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f)), ForceMode.Impulse);

                }

            }

        }
```

This works the first time I press E, however upon trying to do so again, even with a completely untouched gameobject, the Physics.OverlapCapsule doesn't find any colliders, even when there is one very clearly within 10 units of the player.

Comment: Could it be the lack of stamina?

Comment: No, the first debug I've put in still triggers, it just says that there are no targets in the array.